# Cooling wort in ice bath and transferred wort temp

Tags: cooling

I've been using an ice bath to cool my wort that's boiled in a big pot. After 30 mins the wort temp in the bath is usually 20 degrees Celsius. After I transfer it to the fermenter though it's reading 30. I'm not quite sure what I can do now to cool it back to at least 23 so I can pitch the yeast.

Any ideas? And why is the temp so different after transferring? I took readings from all over the pot to ensure it was cool enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to defy the laws of physics.

When cooling with an ice bath, be sure to stir the wort when you think it is at the right temperature, and then measure again. Do not just take measurements at different positions in the wort. Make sure that the temperature is homogeneous by stirring it gently.

Comment: definitely a stirring problem, make sure your stir with a properly sanitized tool and then check temp :)